# Making a simple ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've dealt with ajax calls that only correspond to an action in a certain controller.

I would usually have an action in controller(let's call it 'like' action), and to make an ajax call, I'd do:

In view, `<%= link_to 'like', like_path, :remote => true %>`, and in a partial **js** file, something like `$('.some_class').html("<%= j render 'some_partial' %>");`

Then, an unobstrusive ajax call will be made.

This time, I want a simpler ajax call: when I click on a link, I want to replace a div with another div. But the function is run before I click the link.

In view,

```
$(function teacher_function(){
    $(.become_teacher).html("<%= j render 'become_teacher' %>");
});

<div class="become_teacher">
    change this div
</div>

<%= link_to_function "ajax call", "teacher_function()" %>
```

and in _become_teacher.html.erb, I have `some message` to be put in the become_teacher class div.

This seems a very simple javascript problem, but I wanted to know the most conventional way to do this in a Rails app because all the Rails documents always make ajax calls that correspond to a certain action in a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with sensical, legal syntax first:

```
function teacher_function() {
    $(".become_teacher").html("<%= j render 'become_teacher' %>");
}

<div class="become_teacher">
    change this div
</div>

<%= link_to_function "ajax call", "teacher_function()" %>
```

There is no Ajax here, though.

Comment: Thanks! So the problem was I had a dollar mark around function. But could you explain why this isn't ajax? Instead of reloading the whole page, I'm effectively reloading only the div part of the entire page without affecting the rest. Isn't this what ajax stands for?

Comment: @Maximus Because there's nothing asynchronous about it, no request, just a JavaScript function and DOM manipulation. There no reloading, which one a request. The function ran right away because you told it to; a function as an argument to $ means "run this when the DOM is ready".